# Picture background for canvas particle

Tags: javascript, canvas, particles

I'm trying to create background for every created particle.
Canvas pattern is not working properly. I'm getting this error >> 
"SyntaxError: An invalid or illegal string was specified" 
HTML

```
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

JS

```
(function(){

window.onload = function(){
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
    particles = {},
    particleIndex = 0,
    particleNum = 1;

    canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

    ctx.fillStyle = '#000';
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.width);

    function Particle(){
        this.x = canvas.width / 2;
        this.y = 0;
        this.vx = Math.random() * 10 - 5;
        this.vy = Math.random() * 10 - 5;
        this.gravity = 0.2;
        particleIndex++;
        particles[particleIndex] = this;
        this.id = particleIndex;
        this.test = 0;
        this.maxLife = 100;
    }
    Particle.prototype.draw = function(){
        this.x += this.vx;
        this.y += this.vy;
        this.vy += this.gravity;
        this.test++;
        if ( this.test >= this.maxLife ) {
            delete particles[this.id];
        };

        var img = new Image();
        img.src = 'img/aaa.png';
        var pattern = ctx.createPattern(img,'repeat');

        ctx.fillStyle = pattern;
        ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, 20, 20);
    };


    setInterval(function(){
        ctx.fillStyle = "#000";
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);


        for (var i = 0; i < particleNum; i++) {
            new Particle();
        };

        for(var i in particles) {
            particles[i].draw();
        }

    },30)

}})();
```

I was trying to do this also with ctx.drawImage(), but picture was displayed one time only.

Any tips?:)
[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yhyqs8n5/#&togetherjs=dza7HKRtOs)

Comment: Could you provide a jsfiddle or other example so we know which libraries you're trying to use?

Comment: Im not using any library. It's pure JS. Code above is complete. You can replace "ctx.fillStyle = pattern;" with "ctx.fillStyle = '#f00';" and test. It's working.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is the image being loaded later than its used.

Inside your draw() you have:

```
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = 'img/aaa.png';
    var pattern = ctx.createPattern(img,20,20);
```

It is a bad idea to create new images everytime you want to draw.  I strongly suggest you create the img variable outside of the draw loop.  Once you set the .src of an image, you have to wait until it is loaded to use it.  There is an onload event you can use to let you know when its ready.

Here is an example:

```
 var imgLoaded = false;
 var img = new Image();
 img.src = 'img/aaa.png';
 img.onload = function() { imgLoaded = true; };

 function draw() {
   ...
   if (imgLoaded) {
       var pattern = ctx.createPattern(img, 'repeat');
       ...
   }
   ...
 }
```

Comment: I found an error. 
var pattern = ctx.createPattern(img,20,20); should be >> var pattern = ctx.createPattern(img,'repeat');
But now its creating pattern in background and every particle is just showing part of it. 
I want to create separate background for every particle.
Do you have any idea?:)

Comment: That is a completely different question.  Given your initial question, does my answer solve it?

Comment: Yep. It helped. Thx.

Comment: And its not completly different question.
Look at the title >> "Picture background for canvas particle"